# Angularjs xeditable saving

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I have a form with around 30 fields, once a user edits one and closes the input box the function `save($data, customer.custref)` passes the data and id(custref) to the controller. The problem im having is converting the data to json and then sending via a patch request.

Save function:

```
$scope.save = function(data, id){
    console.log(data);
    $http.patch(API_URL + "v1/customers/" + id, data)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("here");
        },function error(response) {
            console.log('error');
            $scope.error = response.statusText;
        });
};
```

HTML:

```
 <td data-title="'company'" >
     <p class="form-control-static"><a href="#" editable-text="customer.company" onbeforesave="save($data, customer.custref)">
          {{ customer.company || 'empty' }}
     </a></p>
 </td>
```

In the code snippet I am passing `data` to the patch request but this needs to be an object something like otherwise it's not valid json:

```
$scope.updateObj = {

company: data.company ?? 

}
```

I have done something similar before without xeditable, with that I used
ng-model on the input fields and created an object like:

```
$scope.updateObj = {

company: $scope.company, 
name: $scope.name

}
$http.patch(API_URL + "v1/customers/" + id, updateObj){
//......
```

but I can't do that as the input fields are generated for me.I am really stuck and would appreciate any help

Comment: Can you provide an example of what 'data' is once it makes it to the save() function.  What is the result of the console.log(data); ?

Comment: just a string. I managed to get it working by doing `$scope.updateObj = {

company: data 

}` but obviously that wont work when i add any more fields as it will overwrite them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass in the property name as a parameter to save.

**Controller**

```
$scope.save = function(data, id, fieldName){
    console.log(data);

    var patchObj = {};
    patchObj[fieldName] = data;

    $http.patch(API_URL + "v1/customers/" + id, patchObj)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("here");
        },function error(response) {
            console.log('error');
            $scope.error = response.statusText;
        });
};
```

**HTML**

```
 <td data-title="'company'" >
     <p class="form-control-static"><a href="#" 
                                       editable-text="customer.company" 
                                       onbeforesave="save($data, customer.custref, 'company')">
          {{ customer.company || 'empty' }}
     </a></p>
 </td>
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/mo1z4Ju4LiVF9zYGRoNW?p=preview